# GStreamer with VDPAU (h264 acceleration with nVidia cards)

Tags: cuda, h.264, gstreamer, gpgpu, nvidia

I use last version of gstreamer plugins bad and I would like to try VDPAU.
I test with the big buck bunny movie from blender foundation.
I've try with this command :
`gst-launch-0.10 filesrc=/home/alex/big.mp4 ! mp4mux ! vdpauh264dec ! vdpauvideopostprocess ! vdpausink` but it could not link mp4mux with vdph264dec.

I also tried with ffdemux_mov_mp4_m4a_3gp_3g2_mj2 instead of mp4mux and gst-launch fail but with an error message :

```
[...]
Could not create vdpau decoder
[...]
Error returned from vdpau was: An invalid/unsupported VdpDecoderProfile value was supplied
[...]
```

How can I play h264 with VDPAU capabilities of my NVIDIA card?

Thanks in advance for any help, and please excuse my bad english.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

mp4mux is a muxer, not a demuxer. You should indeed use ffdemux_mov_mp4_m4a_3gp_3g2_mj2. The following command line worked for me:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/home/manu/big.mov ! ffdemux_mov_mp4_m4a_3gp_3g2_mj2 ! vdpauh264dec ! vdpauvideopostprocess ! vdpausink
```